# Unable to capture memory allocation failure

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

When I try to allocate a large memory using the 'new' operator in C++, system calls are not working after this memory allocation operation. It seems like the problem is with the memory allocation. However, I am not able to capture the exception.

For better clarity, I have the following MWE.

My main.cpp contains the following lines:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "memallocator.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_ITER = 2000;

int main()
{
    printf("\n 1. output of ls: %d \n", system("ls"));

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_ITER;i++)
    {
        MemAllocator *pCMemAllocator;
        try
        {
            pCMemAllocator = new MemAllocator(); // alocates memory of size BUF_SIZE = 4000*1024;
        } catch(bad_alloc e)
        {
            printf("\nException at %d",i);
            break;
        }

    }
    printf("\nMemory Allocated");
    printf("\n 2. output of ls: %d \n", system("ls"));

    return 0;
}
```

The memallocator.h file is given as:

```
#ifndef MEMALLOCATOR_H
#define MEMALLOCATOR_H

const unsigned long BUF_SIZE = 4000*1024;

class MemAllocator
{
public:
    MemAllocator(){};
private:

    unsigned char ucBuffer [BUF_SIZE];

};

#endif // MEMALLOCATOR_H
```

I compiled it using g++ (version 4.8) on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and got the following output:

```
a.out  main.cpp  memallocator.h

 1. output of ls: 0 

Memory Allocated
 2. output of ls: -1
```

That is, the system("ls") command fails after the memory allocation operation. However, the failure was not captured by the exception handler. I also tried the naive method: allocating zero first to the pointer and checking for zero after memory allocation operation. This method also did not capture the problem with the memory allocation.

If I set the variable MAX_ITER to some small value, say 20, everything works fine.
For higher values of MAX_ITER, the memory exception was supposedly handled by the exception handler. Why is it not happening?

Comment: @demonofnight Because `system` doesn't return a string?

Comment: @demonofnight: system command returns a number on execution. -1 implies Error.

Comment: You are aware of that you try to allocate almost 8GB in your process? While the allocations may succeed, there may not be enough memory left to do other things (like creating new processes like `system` does)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Sorry, It was a mistake. I removed the twice allocation now. The point I wanted to bring out is that I am not able to catch the exception. (I strongly believe that the erratic behavior of system command is due to huge memory allocation).

Comment: Put a trailing newline after your exception output.

Comment: IIRC, Linux doesn't necessarily fail at the point of allocation, but prefers to wait until the allocated memory is first used.

Comment: @molbdnilo: if this is true how will we avoid segmentation fault in linux system caused by a illegal memory access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function is (on Linux and most Posix systems) using the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall, which can fail for several reasons

> EAGAIN: 
>      fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's
>                 page tables and allocate a task structure for the child.
>
> ```
> ENOMEM: fork() failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures 
> because memory is tight.
> ```

So you won't be able to  `fork` if your current process uses a lot of memory (and e.g. if the system does not have enough swap space to hold a copy).

BTW `system(3)` man pages says explicitly that `system` can fail and return....

> ```
>    *  If a child process could not be created, or its status could not
>       be retrieved, the return value is -1.
> ```

Consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)  - proably as `strace -f` to understand the syscalls done by your application.

Notice that `system(3)` is *not* a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (which are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) but a standard library function.

So your huge memory allocation works as you want, but the later call to `system` is failing (and you should test it against failure). There is no memory allocation failure in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer on the 'system' function. In my case, system command was only an example. My question is about NOT capturing the memory exception. Apologies if my question was misleading.

Comment: As I explained, your memory allocation is succeeding.

Comment: @Sooraj there is no memory exception to catch.